# network configuration (bridging) proxmox

Tags: networking, configuration, kvm-virtualization, bridge, proxmox

I bought yesterday an proxmox license. All works fine only the network configuration is very complicated. My network configuration:

```
84.200.50.186 -> hostsystem ip
84.200.50.186 -> VM ip
255.255.255.248 -> netmask
84.200.50.185 -> gateway


auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 84.200.50.186
        netmask 255.255.255.248
        gateway 84.200.50.185


auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
       address  84.200.50.187
       netmask  255.255.255.248
       gateway  84.200.50.185
       bridge_ports eth0
       bridge_stp off
       bridge_fd 0
```

The ip is able to ping but the virtual machine has no connection to the internet.

Any ideas? :-(

Answer (score 7):

Your network configuration is wrong.
The host needs only it's own IP address, and you must configure the VM's network on its side, not on the host one.

vmbr0 is the host's bridge to eth0, so eth0 does not have any configuration. The host's ip address needs to be setted on the vmbr0 interface. If you want your virtual machine to be bridged, you need to bridge it to vmbr0.

Supposing that 84.200.50.187 is the VM's IP address, change the host's network configuration as follow:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet manual

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
    address 84.200.50.186
    netmask 255.255.255.248
    bridge_ports eth0
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_fd 0
    gateway 84.200.50.185
```

On the virtual machine side, configure the network as follow:

- IP Address: 84.200.50.187
- Netmask: 255.255.255.248
- Gateway: 84.200.50.185

It should work.

Comment: I think I was confused about what the proxmox host actually uses as it's internet connection. Is it correct to say that the host actually uses a bridge to a NIC, and then VMs use a bridge to a bridge to a NIC?